# What does the bracket operator do to a FixNum in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Coming from Python I find the following behaviour very surprising:

```
irb(main):211:0> x= 33
=> 33
irb(main):212:0> x[0]
=> 1
irb(main):213:0> x[1]
=> 0
irb(main):214:0> x[2]
=> 0
```

Is there a rationale/philosophy for not raising an error in this example?

Comment: Ruby's [FixNum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html) and Integer values are actually full of methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be a little confused about what this is doing internally, but that's normal when dealing with Ruby because it's quite unlike other scripting languages. Unless you've used [SmallTalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) it might even seem insane.

When Ruby sees the following code:

```
x = 6
x[1]
```

What it's actually doing is this:

```
x.send(:[], 6) # Send :[] method call to x with arguments [ 6 ]
```

The `x` object is free to interpret that however it wants, and the behaviour is typically (though not always) defined by the class `x` belongs to if `x` is a normal instance.

In this case it's returning the bit at a given index, equivalent to `x & (1 << 6) >> 6`.

Sometimes the `[]` method does several things:

```
string = "brackets"

# Retrieve a single character
string[1]
# => "r"

# Retrieve a substring
string[5,2]
# => "et"

# Perform a pattern match
string[/[^aeiou]+/]
# => "br"
```

This also does some pretty crazy things since you can apply it to a Proc as well:

```
fn = lambda { |x| x + 1 }

# Conventional (explicit) call
fn.call(2)
# => 3

# Square bracket method
fn[5]
# => 6
```

Since Ruby leans very heavily on [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), this means that you can write a Proc to fill in where you'd normally have a Hash or an Array and the method receiving your object is none the wiser.

It's this flexibility in leaving the *meaning* of `x[...]` for your own class instance `x` up to you that makes it pretty powerful.

For example:

```
class Bracketeer
  def [](i)
    "%d brackets" % i
  end
end

bracketeer = Bracketeer.new

bracketeer[6]
# => "6 brackets"
```

This simple notation often comes in handy when you're trying to create a minimal interface for a class of yours. In many cases you can use something simple like `[]` to replace what would be a more verbose method like `find_by_id` or `cache_fetch`.

Answer (score 5):

The bracket operator gives you the nth bit of the binary representation:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: Admittedly I should have checked that first, isn't it rather convoluted to for attribute access to call a conversion method and given an *n* binary place? Since unlike elements in an array the binary representation does not physically exist.

Comment: There's no conversion happening here. It's a method that masks out and returns the value of a given bit, basically the same as `v & (1 << n) >> n`. Also what do you mean by "attribute access"? There's no attributes on a number. The binary representation does *of course* exist, since these values are stored as binary internally.

Comment: @tadman That's what I meant, It seems rather weird for `x[i]` to do something other than access a location in memory. The binary representation might exist in memory, but the programming language doesn't have access to it in any real sense - it's not a basic type and requires manipulations of basic types to derive.

Comment: The `[]` method isn't special, it takes an argument and returns an object just like everyone else. You can write your own to do whatever you want. Sometimes it's an array lookup, a hash (dictionary) key retrieval, a database call, or a cache fetch. Every object uses it for different things. For `String` it can even take regular expressions: `"foo"[/oo/]` and for a `lambda` it's a method call. Remember, unlike other languages, `[]` is not an *operator*, it's a *method*.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly.  You'll find that the [manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D) is quite illuminating.

This is returning the binary bit for the bit position value as a zero or one.

Answer (score 1):

It is returning the n'th bit as rightfully observed by @msergeant.

What this means is, for the number 33, its binary representation is:

```
Index : [7][6][5][4] [3][2][1][0]
Bits  :  0  0  1  0   0  0  0  1
```

Which explains the output:

```
irb(main):212:0> x[0]
=> 1
irb(main):213:0> x[1]
=> 0
irb(main):214:0> x[2]
=> 0
```